# WP_Query secondary query failing

Tags: wp-query, loop, query

I'm needing a couple queries on front-page.php and am at a loss why this is not working. My first query works fine, however, my second one specifying the category (or even nothing at all) never returns anything.  Any ideas?

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="details">
    <?php 
        if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); 
        the_content(); 
        endwhile; else : ?>
        <p><?php _e( 'Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.' ); ?></p>
    <?php 
        endif; 
        wp_reset_postdata(); ?>

    <?php
        $secondary_query = new WP_Query( 'category_name=students' );        
        echo '<ul>';
        if ($secondary_query->have_posts()) : while ($secondary_query->have_posts()) : $secondary_query->the_post();
        echo '<li>' . get_the_title() . '</li>';
        endwhile; else : ?>
        <p><?php _e( 'Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.' ); ?></p>
   <?php 
        echo '</ul>';
        endif; 
        wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
        <ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you sure there is a category with slug `students`, and that there are posts attached to it? Saying "it is failing" is a bit too broad, there's no way we can diagnose the problem without more information. Have you tried disabling plugins?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try with get_posts() and foreach loop for the second query instead of WP_Query and then you will have something like this:

```
<?php
$secondary_query = get_posts('category_name=students');
foreach($secondary_query as $secondary_post):
   echo "<li>" . get_the_title($secondary_post->ID) . "</li>";
endforeach;
?>
```

With above like style you don't need wp_reset_query() just make sure you pass the post ID to the functions